# Questions about RF receiver design

Tags: rf, radio, antenna

I'm trying to design a wide band RF receiver(say 5MHz to 5GHz).

The antenna:

- How long would the antenna have to be to pick up this range?
- I read that the antenna width would have to be at least as long as the half wavelength so would I have to use a 30m antenna to receive a 5MHz signal?
- Would I be able to pick up a 5GHz Signal with that same 30m antenna?
- And to pick up the signal the circuit would have to have a resonant frequency equal to that of the RF signal?

Are there any good resources out there I should look at?

Comment: You've got way more than one question here. I'd suggest first asking just about the antenna. If you still think this is a viable project after learning more about that, then give us another question about the receiver circuit.

Comment: half wavelength or λ/4 ???

Comment: The [Biconical antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconical_antenna) is often used for EMI detection purposes, but even that would be challenged over a 3 decade range. Do you want to accurately measure field strength or just detect the presence of RF. What field strengths do you expect? Are you limited to a single antenna?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a very wide range of frequencies needs to be covered usually [Log-peridoc antennas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-periodic_antenna) are used.

I doubt, however, if you can use one single antenna effectively to cover the range of 5MHz to 5GHz (factor 1000!).

Comment: Ok thank you! so it looks like i'll need to use two antennas?

Comment: @nwnoga: I guess you need even more than 2. Some Log-periodic antennas can cover a range of factor ca. 10. I.e. in that case you would still need at least 3: 5-50 MHz, 50-500 MHz, 500-5000 MHz.